# How to limit quantities of discount coupon usage times in laravel

Tags: laravel, coupon, quantities

e.g .. i create a new coupon that can be use 50 times. After used 50 times, it will be expired or cannot use anymore.

coupon quantities will decrease with each use .

Comment: Please show some code and edit your question to a specific error or other problem.